# Computer suddenly and completely dies then boot loops but next day is completely fine

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

Last week my computer unexpectedly completely shutdowns instantly, no freezing, no blue screen, it was as if the power plug was pulled out. It wasn't even doing anything intensive. It then booted up fine. Next day it does the same except this time it powered on for 2 seconds and then shutdowns in a loop about 10 times before it finally booted up.

Yesterday it did the same but was just looping now indefinitely. I tried discounting everything, removing RAM sticks to one, plugging cables in and out again, nothing worked.

So I took it to a PC shop where a couple hours later I was told that it was working completely fine with no issues only hours before I couldn't get it to boot at all. They tested the PSU and said it passed but the grounding light took a while to turn on where usually it was be instantly.

So now I have a PC that works (currently) but could at any time die on me. I freelance on this PC for work so if it dies then I'm losing wages. I'm in the process of buying a completely brand new PC to replace it but I would also quite like to keep this one going for a bit longer.

PC is about 6yrs old:
CPU - Intel Core i7-4790K (not overclocked)
Cooler - Intel Stock
GPU - GTX 970
RAM - Ballistix Tactical 16GB (2x8GB) DDR3
Motherboard - Gigabyte GA-Z97MX-Gaming 5
PSU - EVGA Supernova 650W G1 Gold

Any ideas would be amazing thanks!

UPDATE

A week later without any issues it has suddenly shutdown and won't turn on again. I have tried a new PSU and that turned on and off for a split second and then nothing. The old PSU behaves the same when put back in. So not the PSU.

Comment: This sounds to me like a PSU fault - If I were to guess further, Id guess its a capacitor in the PSU (but dont go opening the PSU it up, those things can bite).

Comment: If the PC is so important to you why haven't you told the PC shop to replace the PSU if it does not work 100% correct? A PSU is cheap and easy to replace.

Comment: The guy at the shop said it wasn't worth replacing for how old it is but I'm not sure I agree with him. I actually have a new PSU on the way from amazon so if it is that then I can fix it and if it isn't that I can use it for the new build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you have relevant messages in the Event Viewer, or any `.dmp` files
in `C:\Windows\Minidump` which date from the day when you had the problems.
If you find any, zip them up and upload them online (Dropbox, OneDrive etc.)
for us to analyze.

First idea, based on the indicator light being late, is about a problem
with the PSU, but it could also be the motherboard.

Think also about the differences in the conditions between your place
and the workshop, such as the temperature and power supply system.

Many times, the only solution is to keep on using the computer until
a passing problem becomes permanent, which is when the repair-shop
can more easily analyze it.

I note also that 6 years is a respectable age for a computer,
at which it might become too costly to maintain.

Comment: There aren't any dump files for the day but looking in Event Viewer there have been 4 Critical Events in the last 7 days. "Kernel-Power" - "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly." Not sure if there's anything else to be seen in that error.

Comment: "Kernel-Power" vaguely points to power issues. Is your computer protected by a UPS?

Comment: It is not, so when it dies it is as if the power was just pulled. It's plugged straight into the wall and the monitor plugged into the other socket was fine. Also last week I was in a completely different house and it happened there as well. I have a new PSU on the way, if it's anything other than the that I'll probably do a new build and use that new PSU in the new build.

Comment: I agree completely.

Comment: I will update this post if that fixes or not. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Upadate: The new PSU doesn't fix the issue and now cuts out immediately. I guess I'll be building a new PC now.